# Get my databases from an old and unable WampServer version

Tags: mysql, database, wampserver

I currently installed a new WampServer version (2.5) wherease an old was previously installed (2.2).

unfortunally, my new WampServer2 doesn't work ; I get a message wich inform me that the "service" cannot be found (cf : line 325 of the config file). But I don't find a way to solve this problem.

So, I installed my 2.5 version in a new folder (c:/wamperserver2/ instead of c:/wamp/) and it works. The problem is I haven't my old SQL databases.

Does someone know how can I get them, from a file for example ?

Regards

Comment: just FYI - the other user attempted to edit the question to make it a bit more understandable - you do want an answer, right?

Comment: Indeed, but I'm not very "confortable" that someone could edit my message without my permission. It's weird...
Now if you don't want to answer, I can understand it :)

Answer (score 2):

After some searchs, I found a way.

**I explain it there :**

1. in the old wamperserver folder, copy the database folders from `bin\mysql\mysqlX.X.X\data\`
2. paste them in `bin\mysql\mysqlX.X.X\data\` of the new wampserver folder
3. then, in the same folder, rename the file `"ibdata1"` in `"ibdata1.bak"`
4. Finally, get the one from the old WampServer folder

Maybe it will be necessary (but it didn't work for me) to cut/paste the users file (`user.frm`, `user.MDY`, `user.MYU`) from the `data\mysql\` from the old wamperserver folder to the new wampserver folder. I think these files contain MySQL users, but this solution wasn't good for me (mysql 5.5.24 to mysql.5.6.17).